# Getting notifications for new TV seasons even though notifications are turned off in Google Play

Tags: notifications

I get notifications for new TV seasons even thought I have turned the following notifications off in Google Play Movies & TV:

- About TV Shows
- About watchlist
- About rewards

Here is what the notification looks like:
[image]

I would expect that deactivating "About TV Shows" would stop me from getting them, but they keep popping up. How to I exorcise them?

I am using an LG G6 with Android 7.0.